# WPF .NET4.0 Content control growing out of screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Ive got an issue which has been frustrating the heck out of me for a while. The content which is displayed grows out of screen. I.e. no window sizing is applied.

Following is what Ive tried:

```xml
<Window ...
        d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1024"
        MinHeight="768" MinWidth="1024"  
        mc:Ignorable="d" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"  WindowState="Maximized"
        Closed="WindowClosed" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

Ive tried setting `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` on both the host and main window and still no luck.

and in code behind Window:

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        MinWidth = ActualWidth;
        MinHeight = ActualHeight;
        ClearValue(SizeToContentProperty);
    }
```

Code on the host control:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height= "*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl x:Name="content"
                    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ContentToDisplay}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Ive tried sticking the `ContentControl` in a `ViewBox`, `DockPanel` and still no luck. As soon as I set the content to something "big" (which is within a `ScrollViewer`) it doesnt bother contain it. What Im trying to achieve is to simply contain the content within the content control within screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe as a workaround you could listen to [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) and disable the auto-resizing when you hit the dimensions of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

You have the window marked SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight", so the content is going to size to what it contains.  That isn't posted, so it's difficult to say what is causing it.  Are you using DataBinding to set any sizes, for example?

Also, you are not setting the maximum width and height of the window to the screen size.  That would at least prevent it from getting larger than the screen.

The best thing to do, perhaps, would be to set the window to a specific size, and then in the codebehind, in the Loaded event, set the window to the desired size, or instead set it to maximized once loaded.

Comment: Hi, I tried taking out `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and sticking in a `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight`. What that seems to do is to stick the content and make it somewhat small (even with `Stretch` set on content) when there is still a fair bit of screen real estate left!

Comment: OK, but it prevented the window from growing off the screen.  Did you try maximizing or resizing the window to the desired size in the code behind?